# Google Analytics Filter SPAM contain a word by campaign source

Tags: google-analytics, bots, block, spam, referrer

My website is under attack by click-bait bots disguised as a SEO solutions.

Those bots are messing with my numbers everyday...

When ever i discover a fake referral URL trying to get me, I filter / block them by their campaign source that usually includes the word "SEO".

Filter works fine for explicit source, but those bots hit me every-time with a new URL campaign source. So I end-up with tens of filters desperate trying to block all those!

Here are some examples:

```
autoseo-b2b-seo-service.com
seo-services-wordpress.com
krumbleead-ads.info
seo-services-b2b.com
growth-hackingead.info
autoseo-b2b-services.com
seo-b2b-analytics.com
seo-b2b.com
seo-for-b2b.com
```

I'm looking for RegEx filter solution to block any referrer that includes the word "seo-" SEO word with a dash.

I'm not RegEx savvy... But i just added (as exclude) & trying out the following:

```
.*seo-.*$
```

Q1. Does this look correct?
Q2. Better solution to block all those F**** bots?
Q3. How many cups of coffee did you have today? :P

Answer (score 0):

**Im a bit rusty on regex. Buuut last time i checked:**

> Q1: Does this look correct?

If you want to check for it as a single, full word, it's `\bTest\b`**\b represents a "word boundary"**

So `^.*\b(seo)\b.*$` I believe =)

> Q2: Better solution to block all those *expletive* bots?

I think its best solution you can have really.

> Q3: How many cups of coffee did you have today?

I drink tea. Mint tea normally. But i've been busy all day so i've only had one! Mainly making my way through this large bottle of water

**Further Reading: https://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html**